# How to dynamically create an AnimationDrawable from a tiled image

Tags: android, animation, drawable, oncreate

In the game I am currently programming, I have a tiled image with different animation frames in a 4x3 matrix. I would like to create an `AnimationDrawable` consisting of each of these frames in sequence. However, I am only aware of making animations with entire images being frames. Can someone help me as to how to do this? If this could be done in XML, that's even better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bitmap.createBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to create the clipped bitmaps from the big bitmap, and use [AnimationDrawable.addFrame](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html#addFrame%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20int%29) to add the bitmap to the AnimationDrawable.